# Partiton data into 20 approximately equal partitions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning

I have huge amount of data coming from a source and each record has a dimension dim1. Dim1 can have up to 1 million unique values. Some of them will have a lot of data and some will have less. For e.g. Dim1value1 may have 100K records, Dim1value2 may have 1 million records, Dim1value3 may have 10 records and so on.

Now I want to group them into somewhat equal partitions so data related to each Dim1 go into one group and I want to create about 20 somewhat equal group.

Basically every record having Dim1Value1 should go into one group and so on.
Here is script that shows how ntile does not do it.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#t') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #t

CREATE TABLE #t
(
    Dim1 varchar(100),
    numberofrecs int
)

DECLARE @counter int = 1

WHILE(@counter < = 100)
BEGIN
    INSERT #t
        SELECT 
            'Dim1value' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(10)), 
            CAST(RAND()  * 100 AS INT)

    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END

SELECT * FROM #t

SELECT 
    NTILE(5) OVER(order by numberofrecs),
    Dim1, * 
FROM #t
```

Comment: Is it mysql or sql-server? update the tags and keep only the relevant vendor.

Comment: If SQL Server consider NTile()  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx

Comment: I don't think ntile will do it. I considered it but it just sorts the measure and then divides my dimension in n number of groups. basically it will put all the dimension which have highest numbers in same group. this is not what I want...this sql script will demonostrate it...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to split your dim1 would be:

SELECT ROWNUMBER() OVER(order by numberofrecs) % 20 + 1 AS PartNr, 
Dim1, 
* 
FROM #t
ORDER BY 1

This ia not a perfect algorithm, it will just approximate the groups by ordering by the number of records and pseudo partition using modulo function. For a better algorithm, it would make sense to implement a CLR stored procedure using object oriented logic instead of relational approach. Another way would be to have an ETL process analyze your data and chose the right partition.

I believe you misunderstood the concept of partitioning. While you should choose the cluster for your partition, trying to split data as much as possible  equally over partitions, the amount of partitions is not a constant value in a real environment. The whole purpose of partitioning is to optimize data storage, dml and querying. You might also want to implement a sliding window but that would be really complex and unintuitive with your approach. Is the data in your dim1 fixed and unalterable? If so,  you could choose your considered approach. If not, you need to find an index that fits clustering into partitions. For example a date value could be a candidate and partitioning this date into weeks, mobths or years or so.

Comment: I did something similar. My problem is I will almost ALWAYS be querying from one value of Dim1. And I don't want to be hitting multiple partitions for it. ANd when I query for a particular value of Dim1, I will query a lot of history so partitioning by day or week does not make sense. If I do a dumb partition by just value of Dim1, e.g. Dim1value1 to value100 goes into 1 , value 101 to 200 goes in 2 and so on, I will end up with unequal partitions...like Dim1value1 might have more number of records if you add dim1value2 to value200 all together...